# Create a pagination in blog page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi everyone I create my own template in wordpress... I want to show the paginate in the blog page to show only 4 post per page for this I have this.

This is my consult to get the post

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
$lista_post = new WP_Query($args);
```

I have my loop for show the post like this...

```
 <?php while ($lista_post->have_posts()) : $lista_post->the_post(); ?>
  ....
      <?php endwhile; ?>  

      <div class="row enlaces_post">
        <div class="col-xs-6 "><?php next_posts_link( '<<< Older Entries', $lista_post->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3"> <?php previous_posts_link( 'Recent Entries >>>' );  ?></div>

      </div>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

but when I click in the "older Entries" or "Recent entries" showme always the same post. that is the same that when I open the blog page

any idea why do that?

Comment: You should be creating a post archive template (e.g. `index.php`, `archive.php`, or `category.php`) as this will make it much simpler (all you need to do is modify the default query to change `posts_per_page`).  This method of creating a page template with a custom `WP_Query` as a blog listing makes things unnecessarily more complicated as you will need to include pagination vars for pagination to work correctly.  Refer the to the Template Hierarchy on the WP Codex for more information about template types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I include this into my query

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => $post_page,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
$lista_post = new WP_Query($args);
```

and everything work fine!